# What do you call this equivalence relation? $A \simeq B$ if $A = P^t BP$ for some invertible matrix $P$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-decomposition

If $A, B$ are square matrices with coefficients in some ring, we say that $A$ is **similar** to $B$ if $A = PBP^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $P$.  Similar matrices represent the same linear operator with respect to different bases.

Now another equivalence relation is to set $A \simeq B$ is $A = P^tAP$ for some invertible matrix $P$, where $P^t$ denotes the transpose.  Two matrices are equivalent if they give the same bilinear form with respect to different bases.

What is this equivalence relation usually called? In Jacobson's *Basic Algebra*, he says that $A$ and $B$ are **cogredient**.  But I haven't seen this terminology elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These names/terminologies are common, but completely opaque and non-descriptive, indeed. Much like saying a subgroup is "normal" suggests nothing at all about the feature it apparently has.

The operational point is that $A \to PAP^{-1}$ re-expresses the linear map given by $A$ under the change of basis given by $P$. Nowadays, the specific matrix operation might be called *conjugation* of $A$ by $P$. In any case, it is the way to see the matrix of a linear transformation under a change of basis.

The change $A \to P^\top A P$ is change of coordinates when using a matrix $A$ to represent a _quadratic_form_ $v\to v^\top Av$, for vectors $v$.

So, apart from the common-but-unhelpful labels, these are change-of-coordinates for two different uses of a matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1):

According to Horn & Johnson, *Matrix Analysis* (p. 281): Such matrices are called *congruent* or $\,^T\!$*congruent* ("tee-congruent"), and if $B = S^*AS$ for some invertible $S$ (where $S^*$ denotes conjugate transpose), then $A$ and $B$ are called **congruent* ("star-congruent") or *conjunctive*.

The terms $\,^T\!$*congruent* and **congruent* are unambiguous and easy to remember. I don't like *cogredient* here: it's unusual and it's been used to mean other things. In Berman & Plemmons, *Nonnegative Matrices in the Mathematical Sciences* (p. 27), two matrices are called *cogredient* if they're related by conjugation via a permutation matrix: $A = P^t B P$ for some permutation matrix $P$. In keeping with the theme, maybe we should call such matrices $\,^\pi\!$*congruent*?